# Android - Kotlin : Instantiate an object once inside the class that extends application and use it in all activities

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, singleton, companion-object

My goal would be to instantiate an object inside the class that extends the Application class and then use it statically in all activities, es:

Suppose we have a class to be used statically or with the singleton pattern

```
class MyObject( arg1: Any){

   fun OneFunction(){
     .....
   }

}
```

Suppose we have declared the application with the name of App in the Manifest (so as to create the App class that extends Application ())

```
class App : Application(){

 override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

  }

}
```

The goal is then to be able to use the object statically in any activity

```
class MainActivity : AòppCompactActivity(){
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         MyObject.OneFunction()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple case, you're actually missing a class that would act as the globally accessible object instance container.

```
class MyObject(arg1: Any){
   fun oneFunction() {
       // ...
   }
}    

class App : Application() {
   override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
      Deps.myObject = MyObject(Any())
   }
}
```

Where `Deps` is

```
object Deps {
    lateinit var myObject: MyObject
}
```

And then

```
class MainActivity : AppCompactActivity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         Deps.myObject.oneFunction()
     }
}
```

Comment: I think `Deps` is not required, we can do using `companion` itself

Answer (score 1):

Create `companion` inside MyObject and instantiate in overridden of `Application` class

```
class MyObject : App() { //extends your App or in-build Application 

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    instance= this
}

fun oneFunction() {
    // ...
}
companion object{
    lateinit var instance: MyObject
}
}
```

use like this in any activity

```
MyObject.instance.oneFunction();
```

Comment: I couldn't use your solution as MyObject has a constructor

Comment: You don't need constructor if passing context only, because `MyObject.instance` itself gives you context of `Application` class

Comment: What if you need something else to build MyObject? (Whether it's a primitive object or a more complex one)?

Answer (score 0):

Before your solutions, I was using the SingletonHolder pattern

```
open class SingletonHolder<out T, in A>(private val constructor: (A) -> T) {

    @Volatile
    private var instance: T? = null

    fun getInstance(arg: A): T {
        return when {
            instance != null -> instance!!
            else -> synchronized(this) {
                if (instance == null) instance = constructor(arg)
                instance!!
            }
        }
    }
}


class MyManager private constructor(context: Context) {

    fun doSomething() {
        ...
    }

    companion object : SingletonHolder<MyManager, Context>(::MyManager)
}
```

And inside activities :

```
MyManager.getInstance(context).doSomething()
```